# ¿Cómo hacer que un diccionario el cual las llaves tienen diferente tamaño un dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo este diccionario como ejemplo de lo que me pasa

```
import pandas as pd
diccionario = {'nombres':["mario", "jose", "diego", "maria", "laura"], 'apellidos':["rojas", "martinez", "cardenas", "rozo", "fernandez", "paez", "jaramillo", "acosta"], 'profesion':["ingenero", "doctor", "profesor", "mecanico"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(diccionario)
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me da este error:

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Comment: max_len = len(max(diccionario.values(), key = len));for key, value in diccionario.items():;diccionario[key] += [None] * (max_len - len(value))

Comment: que pena soy nuevo en esto y no entendí muy bien que hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a proponer una solución que resuelve el problema con una sola línea. Entiendo que, ya que estás empezando, esta solución no es muy adecuada para tí ya que será difícil de comprender. No obstante la pongo por si fuera de utilidad a otros que den con esta pregunta.

La línea "mágica" es:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(*diccionario.values()), columns=diccionario)
```

Y el resultado es:

```
  nombres  apellidos profesion
0   mario      rojas  ingenero
1    jose   martinez    doctor
2   diego   cardenas  profesor
3   maria       rozo  mecanico
4   laura  fernandez      None
5    None       paez      None
6    None  jaramillo      None
7    None     acosta      None
```

### Explicación

La "magia" se basa en la función `zip_longest()` de la biblioteca estándar `itertools`. Esta función recibe varios parámetros, cada uno de los cuales ha de ser una lista (o iterable). El resultado de la función es otro iterable, en el cual, según vayas iterando por el mismo, obtienes cada vez una tupla en la que cada elemento se toma de cada una de las listas.

Por ejemplo, si le pasas las listas `zip_longest([1,2,3], ["a", "b", "c"])` el resultado es un iterable en el cual, al iterar, obtendrías la primera vez `(1, "a")`, la segunda vez `(2, "b")`  y la tercera `(3, "c")`.

En realidad eso mismo es lo que hace la función `zip()` de Python. La diferencia está cuando las listas que le pasas no tienen todas la misma longitud. En ese caso, `zip()` se detiene en cuanto la lista más corta se acabe, mientras que `zip_longest()` continúa hasta que la lista más larga se acabe, rellenando con `None` los elementos de la tupla que no existan en otras listas.

Un ejemplo:

```
for tupla in zip_longest([1,2], ["a", "b", "c", "d"], [10, 20, 30]):
   print(tupla)
```

sale:

```
(1, 'a', 10)
(2, 'b', 20)
(None, 'c', 30)
(None, 'd', None)
```

Así pues el truco es aplicar esta función a las listas que hay dentro de tu diccionario, es decir, a `diccionario.values()`. Pero no podemos pasarle a `zip_longest()` el resultado de `diccionario.values()`, pues estaríamos pasando un único parámetro, y queremos pasarle tres en este caso (o en general tantos como elementos tiene tu diccionario). Para eso tenemos el operador `*` que "desempaqueta" una serie de elementos en un parámetro separado para cada uno. Por tanto:

```
for tupla in zip_longest(*diccionario.values()):
   print(tupla)
```

produce

```
('mario', 'rojas', 'ingenero')
('jose', 'martinez', 'doctor')
('diego', 'cardenas', 'profesor')
('maria', 'rozo', 'mecanico')
('laura', 'fernandez', None)
(None, 'paez', None)
(None, 'jaramillo', None)
(None, 'acosta', None)
```

Que es justo lo que necesitábamos. Esto ya se le puede pasar a `pd.DataFrame()` para que cree con ello una tabla. Sólo queda añadir el parámetro `columns=diccionario` para que use como nombres para las columnas las claves del diccionario y llegar así al resultado deseado.

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` exige que para un `DataFrame` todas las columnas tengan el mismo número de datos, no puede haber columnas con más datos que otras. Por ello en el error te dice

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

La columnas `nombres` tiene cinco datos, la columna `apellidos` ocho y la columna `profesión` cuatro. Tienes que hacer que todas tengan el mismo número de datos. La forma más sencilla de conseguir esto, **si los datos son correctos** es añadiendo `None` en todas las columnas que no haya datos.

Para esto, el comentario de @Danis es muy bueno, voy a explicarlo:

## 1. Averiguar el tamaño máximo de nuestras columnas

```
tamano_maximo = len(max(diccionario.values(), key = len))
```

Lo que sucede aquí es lo siguiente:

- El método `.values()` de un diccionario nos devuelve los valores de dicho diccionario, es decir las listas que tienes.
- `max()` nos devuelve el número máximo que hay en un conjunto de datos, pero en este caso le hemos pasado el parametro `key=len`, es decir, le hemos dicho que nos devuelva la lista de valores con la longitud máxima de nuestro conjunto de valores.
- Una vez nos la devuelve, le pedimos con `len()` que nos diga cual es la longitud de dicha lista, que es ocho, **ocho es el número máximo de datos que va a tener una columna** por tanto, el resto de columnas deben tener ocho datos también

## 2. Añadir `None` en el resto de columnas

Ahora vamos a añadir `None` al resto de columnas para que todas tengan la misma longitud.

```
for key, value in diccionario.items():
    diccionario[key] += [None] * (tamano_maximo - len(value))
```

- El método `.items()` nos devuelve un iterable de las clave valor de nuestro diccionario, por lo que podemos iterar por las clave, valor
- En cada iteracción le decimos que añada `None` a nuestras columnas, hasta que la columna tenga un tamaño de ocho, esto lo hacemos con el operador `+=` creandonos una lista de `None` de tamaño que falte para llegar a ocho, `[None] * (tamano_maximo - len(value))`

Por último ya podemos crear nuestro `DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame(diccionario)
```

**Salida:**

```
 nombres  apellidos profesion
0   mario      rojas  ingenero
1    jose   martinez    doctor
2   diego   cardenas  profesor
3   maria       rozo  mecanico
4   laura  fernandez      None
5    None       paez      None
6    None  jaramillo      None
7    None     acosta      None
```

## Advertencia

He utilizado indistintamente las palabras *columnas* y *valores*, en `Pandas` son lo mismo, ya que los *valores* de un diccionario, son los valores de las columnas